# Loss of configurations after unattended upgrade

Tags: shortcut-keys, 22.04, mate, unattended-upgrades, tap-to-click

I'm in Ubuntu MATE 22.04.
Today after logging in, I noticed that various subsystems were messed up.
So far I noticed:

- no tapping on the touchpad (no simple, double, or triple tap)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> won't open a terminal
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> won't snap left/right/maximize a window
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> won't lock my session anymore
- Icons for recycle bin and computer appeared on Desktop

  - New icons on Desktop:

    [image: New icons on Desktop]
- Icons on tray got changed and tray behavior changed (I have to right click Network to get options)

  - New icons on tray:

    [image: New icons on tray]
- Dragging window to the corners won't snap anymore either
- Wallpaper will sometimes be replaced by a default one (but only sometimes, after rebooting).

I noticed an unattended upgrade on the same day. My `/var/log/apt/history.log` has some `xorg` and `gtk` unattended upgrades (output below).

I went on to try and fix each problem on its own, but already the usual "tap to click" solution won't work: I tried modifying `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` and adding the "Tapping" line below, which does nothing even after reboot.

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "True"
EndSection
```

So, can anyone see what would affect so many different subsystems? Is there a was to revert it?
Output of `/var/log/apt/history.log` below (edited down to most recent and relevant installs):

```
Start-Date: 2022-07-12  16:18:49
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: avatar (1000)
Install: linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-41.44, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-41-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0-41.44, automatic), linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-41:amd64 (5.15.0-41.44, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-41.44, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-41-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0-41.44, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-41.44, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-41-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0-41.44, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-41.44, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-41:amd64 (5.15.0-41.44, automatic)
Upgrade: libedata-book-1.2-26:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), libebook-1.2-20:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), libecal-2.0-1:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), linux-image-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0.40.39, 5.15.0.41.40), libedataserver-1.2-26:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), udev:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), evolution-data-server:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64 (40.0-3ubuntu2, 40.0-3ubuntu3), virtualbox:amd64 (6.1.32-dfsg-1build1, 6.1.34-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1), libhwloc-plugins:amd64 (2.7.0-2, 2.7.0-2ubuntu1), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.40.42, 5.15.0.41.43), virtualbox-guest-x11:amd64 (6.1.32-dfsg-1build1, 6.1.34-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1), evolution-data-server-common:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (103.0.5060.53-1, 103.0.5060.114-1), systemd-timesyncd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), libpam-systemd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), linux-oem-20.04:amd64 (5.15.0.40.42, 5.15.0.41.43), apparmor:amd64 (3.0.4-2ubuntu2, 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.1), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.15.0.40.42, 5.15.0.41.43), linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.15.0.40.42, 5.15.0.41.43), libsystemd0:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), libsystemd0:i386 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), libnss-systemd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), linux-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0.40.39, 5.15.0.41.40), libcamel-1.2-63:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), systemd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), virtualbox-guest-utils:amd64 (6.1.32-dfsg-1build1, 6.1.34-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1), libudev1:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), libudev1:i386 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), linux-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.40.42, 5.15.0.41.43), isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2, 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.1), libebook-contacts-1.2-3:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), libedataserverui-1.2-3:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2, 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.1), linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.15.0.40.42, 5.15.0.41.43), linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.15.0.40.42, 5.15.0.41.43), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.40.42, 5.15.0.41.43), linux-headers-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0.40.39, 5.15.0.41.40), gnome-keyring:amd64 (40.0-3ubuntu2, 40.0-3ubuntu3), libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.20+dfsg-2build1, 2.0.20+dfsg-2ubuntu1.22.04.1), libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (2.0.20+dfsg-2build1, 2.0.20+dfsg-2ubuntu1.22.04.1), libedata-cal-2.0-1:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), virtualbox-qt:amd64 (6.1.32-dfsg-1build1, 6.1.34-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1), systemd-sysv:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.3, 249.11-0ubuntu3.4), libhwloc15:amd64 (2.7.0-2, 2.7.0-2ubuntu1), gnome-keyring-pkcs11:amd64 (40.0-3ubuntu2, 40.0-3ubuntu3), virtualbox-dkms:amd64 (6.1.32-dfsg-1build1, 6.1.34-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1), libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 (3.44.1-0ubuntu2, 3.44.2-0ubuntu1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-40.43, 5.15.0-41.44)
End-Date: 2022-07-12  16:21:13

Start-Date: 2022-07-14  12:44:49
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-image-5.15.0-39-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-39.42), linux-modules-5.15.0-39-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-39.42), linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-39-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-39.42)
End-Date: 2022-07-14  12:44:53

Start-Date: 2022-07-14  12:44:57
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.15.0-39-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-39.42)
End-Date: 2022-07-14  12:44:57

Start-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:01
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.15.0-39:amd64 (5.15.0-39.42)
End-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:02

Start-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:06
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: git-man:amd64 (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.2, 1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.4)
End-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:08

Start-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:11
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: git:amd64 (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.2, 1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.4)
End-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:12

------ XORG unattended upgrades -------

Start-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:16
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.1), xserver-common:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.1)
End-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:17

Start-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:21
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2, 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.1)
End-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:22

------ XORG unattended upgrades -------

Start-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:26
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: thunderbird:amd64 (1:91.9.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 1:91.11.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-07-14  12:45:29

Start-Date: 2022-07-16  17:15:50
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python3.10:amd64 (3.10.4-3, 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1), libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-3, 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1), libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-3, 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1), libpython3.10:amd64 (3.10.4-3, 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1), libpython3.10-dev:amd64 (3.10.4-3, 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1), python3.10-dev:amd64 (3.10.4-3, 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1), python3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-3, 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2022-07-16  17:15:54

Start-Date: 2022-07-16  17:15:57
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1, 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1), libpython2.7:i386 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1, 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1), python2.7:amd64 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1, 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1), libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1, 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1), libpython2.7-minimal:i386 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1, 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1), libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1, 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1), libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 (2.7.18-13ubuntu1, 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1)
End-Date: 2022-07-16  17:16:00

Start-Date: 2022-07-16  17:16:03
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libhttp-daemon-perl:amd64 (6.13-1, 6.13-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2022-07-16  17:16:04

Start-Date: 2022-07-19  13:46:23
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.36.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.36.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.36.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.36.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.36.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.36.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.36.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.36.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-07-19  13:46:26

Start-Date: 2022-07-19  16:40:28
Commandline: apt install cmake gcc-arm-none-eabi libnewlib-arm-none-eabi build-essential
Requested-By: avatar (1000)
Install: binutils-arm-none-eabi:amd64 (2.38-3ubuntu1+15build1, automatic), libstdc++-arm-none-eabi-dev:amd64 (15:10.3-2021.07-4+17, automatic), libnewlib-arm-none-eabi:amd64 (3.3.0-1.3), libstdc++-arm-none-eabi-newlib:amd64 (15:10.3-2021.07-4+17, automatic), libjsoncpp25:amd64 (1.9.5-3, automatic), gcc-arm-none-eabi:amd64 (15:10.3-2021.07-4), dh-elpa-helper:amd64 (2.0.9ubuntu1, automatic), librhash0:amd64 (1.4.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), cmake-data:amd64 (3.22.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), cmake:amd64 (3.22.1-1ubuntu1), libnewlib-dev:amd64 (3.3.0-1.3, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-07-19  16:40:48

Start-Date: 2022-07-19  17:27:00
Commandline: apt install minicom
Requested-By: avatar (1000)
Install: lrzsz:amd64 (0.12.21-10, automatic), minicom:amd64 (2.8-2)
End-Date: 2022-07-19  17:27:01

Start-Date: 2022-07-19  18:13:35
Commandline: apt install automake autoconf build-essential texinfo libtool libftdi-dev libusb-1.0-0-
Requested-By: avatar (1000)
Install: libltdl-dev:amd64 (2.4.6-15build2, automatic), libtool:amd64 (2.4.6-15build2), libftdi-dev:amd64 (0.20-4ubuntu1), libusb-dev:amd64 (2:0.1.12-32build3, automatic), libftdi1:amd64 (0.20-4ubuntu1, automatic)
Upgrade: libcamera0:amd64 (0.r3686.g3fa79cc6-1~ubuntu22.04, 0.r3704.gba643593-1~ubuntu22.04)
Remove: celluloid:amd64 (0.20-2), xc3sprog:amd64 (0+svn795+dfsg-4), sane-utils:amd64 (1.1.1-5), update-manager:amd64 (1:22.04.9), libgusb2:amd64 (0.3.10-1), mpv:amd64 (0.34.1-1ubuntu3), printer-driver-splix:amd64 (2.0.0+svn315-7fakesync1build3), tlp:amd64 (1.5.0-1ubuntu3), mate-desktop-environment-core:amd64 (1.26.0+1ubuntu6), bluez-cups:amd64 (5.64-0ubuntu1), libokular5core9:amd64 (4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 (1:0.9.6.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:22.04.11), libcolorhug2:amd64 (1.4.6-1), colord:amd64 (1.4.6-1), libavdevice58:amd64 (7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), rhythmbox-plugins:amd64 (3.4.4-5ubuntu1), ffmpeg:amd64 (7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), system-config-printer-udev:amd64 (1.5.16-0ubuntu3), tlp-rdw:amd64 (1.5.0-1ubuntu3), libgpod-common:amd64 (0.8.3-16build2), libsane-hpaio:amd64 (3.21.12+dfsg0-1), libmpv1:amd64 (0.34.1-1ubuntu3), libmtp9:amd64 (1.1.19-1build1), usbutils:amd64 (1:014-1build1), ubuntu-mate-core:amd64 (1.282), libgphoto2-port12:amd64 (2.5.27-1build2), kolourpaint:amd64 (4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1), libspa-0.2-bluetooth:amd64 (0.3.53.r23.ge1cb7c6-1~ubuntu22.04), update-notifier:amd64 (3.192.54), libusb-1.0-0:amd64 (2:1.0.25-1ubuntu2), ipp-usb:amd64 (0.9.20-1), gvfs-backends:amd64 (1.48.2-0ubuntu1), usb-modeswitch:amd64 (2.6.1-3ubuntu2), okular:amd64 (4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1), gnome-firmware:amd64 (41.0-1), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.99.22.2), libkf5khtml-bin:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), libhpmud0:amd64 (3.21.12+dfsg0-1), libftdi1-2:amd64 (1.5-5build3), libkf5khtml5:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), libkf5sane5:amd64 (21.12.3-0ubuntu1), hplip:amd64 (3.21.12+dfsg0-1), wine64-development:amd64 (6.0+repack-1ubuntu1), printer-driver-gutenprint:amd64 (5.3.3-9), ubuntu-mate-desktop:amd64 (1.282), apturl:amd64 (0.5.2ubuntu22), simple-scan:amd64 (42.0-1), ubuntu-standard:amd64 (1.481), libwine-development:amd64 (6.0+repack-1ubuntu1), usbmuxd:amd64 (1.1.1-2build2), okular-extra-backends:amd64 (4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1), libdc1394-25:amd64 (2.2.6-4), libgphoto2-6:amd64 (2.5.27-1build2), cups:amd64 (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1), libsane1:amd64 (1.1.1-5), libflashrom1:amd64 (1.2-5build1), libfwupdplugin5:amd64 (1.7.5-3), shotwell:amd64 (0.30.14-1ubuntu6), printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 (3.21.12+dfsg0-1), phonon4qt5:amd64 (4:4.11.1-4), phonon4qt5-backend-vlc:amd64 (0.11.3-1), fwupd:amd64 (1.7.5-3), libmtp-runtime:amd64 (1.1.19-1build1), vlc-plugin-base:amd64 (3.0.16-1build7)
End-Date: 2022-07-19  18:13:58

---- Problem occurred here ----
```

Comment: I was between editing it down or uploading the whole thing since I don't know what caused it. I have left only the recent/relevant ones now.

Comment: Okay, you found an upgraded Xorg package. Next, go to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com and see exactly what got changed. See if those line up with the symptoms you are suffering. Claims that "*an upgrade caused it*" are common, but are true only occasionally...so I suggest putting aside that possible cause for now and focusing on troubleshooting your actual symptoms. For example, review your logs around the time before you noticed the change.